# Kali Linux 2018 crash when connecting an USB device

Tags: kali-linux, usb, mtp

After upgrading to kali 2018(kernel 4.14), Something went wrong. Whenever I connect my android device to any of the USB port, it logs out and system returns to logging on screen, shutting down all the processes. After logging in, it behaves like the computer has been shut down.All the work/processes are lost.

I tried setting MTP to "charge only", but the behaviour seems same.
I tried replacing my android device with another. also tried different USB cable.

Comment: Thanks, @GAD3R, it seems the problem was caused by a genome extension called "places status indicator", disabling this, fixes the bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://bugs.kali.org/view.php?id=4488). 
It is a bug produces by a gnome-shell extension called "places status indicator".

Disabling this extension solves the problem.

To disable this extension, go to terminal and type
`gnome-shell-extension-prefs`
and scroll down to places status indicator and turn it off.